# How to prevent back div from showing through the front div

Tags: html

I am struggling to get a hamburger menu to work correctly.

It drops down as expected, but for some reason, it does not cover up the elements behind it. In other words, the background appears transparent.  But I cannot find a way to prevent this.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Hamburger Menu does not hide the back elements]

```
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Page 3" class="e-menu-item e-focused" id="3">Page 3</li>
```

I have tried setting the opacity to 1, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

So how do I fix?

```
  .e-menu-item{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the z-index to something higher.

```
.e-menu-item{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Thats working for me Jack!

Answer (score 0):

You must put quotes `' or "` at the strings in CSS. Try like this:

```css
.e-menu-item{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: 'white';
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).